# How to cycle between two windows when I have more than two open?

Tags: window

Scenario: I have several (more than 2) windows open. I actively work with two of them. How do I best jump from one window to another, and back, with *one* command?

I use ace-window; it's great but I don't want to press window number every time.
I know about `next-window` / `prev-window`, but these are two different commands.

What I'm looking for is something that remembers what the previous windows was when I select another window, and gets back to it. Invoked repeatedly, it would switch between the last two windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>-style.

Where do I look?

Comment: I use `fn` plus one of the arrow keys to go in any direction, including in and out of the minibuffer (if it is active) -- see the built-in library `windmove`.

Comment: @lawlist: I know about windmove. What I'm looking for is a way _not to think_ about the direction required, especially if the windows have a few other windows between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to write your own command is to use the built in `get-mru-window` function.

For example:

```
(defun my-flip-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win  (get-mru-window nil nil t)))
    (when win (select-window win))))
```

This looks for the most-recently-used window in the current frame that is not the currently selected window.

Here is a variation that works across visible frames:

```
(defun my-flip-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win  (get-mru-window 'visible nil t)))
    (when win
      (select-frame-set-input-focus (window-frame win))
      (select-window win))))
```

As mentioned in the comments, here's a variation that works when there's only one window (switching to the most recent buffer):

```
(defun flip-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win  (get-mru-window 'visible t t)))
    (if win
        (progn
          (select-frame-set-input-focus (window-frame win))
          (select-window win))
      (mode-line-other-buffer))))
```

Comment: Nailed it!  This one is much better than the one I put together.  Nice find on `get-mru-window`.

Comment: I ended up adding this to my config with an additional variation: when there is only one frame/window (get-mru-window returns nil), then call `mode-line-other-buffer`. That way I have one key that flips back and forth between two buffers in any window configuration.

Comment: Great. I love that last variation @glucas. Thank you.
Here is how I wrote it and it works. Is that the best way to do it? (defun my-switch-to-previous-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win (get-mru-window nil nil t)))
    (if win (select-window win)
      (mode-line-other-buffer))))

Answer (score 6):

If you are already using `ace-window`, then you can use the command `aw-flip-window` to flip back and forth between two windows. By default this is bound to `n` in the ace-window `aw-dispatch-alist`.

That means that you can invoke ace-window and hit `n` instead of a window number to flip back to the previous window. You could also bind `aw-flip-window` to some other key.

Note that this will only flip back to a window that was previously selected by ace-window. If you often switch windows with other commands you may want a more general solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple command, lightly tested, that will switch you to
the most recently visited window:

```el
(defvar recent-window nil
  "The most recently visited window.")

(defun switch-to-recent-window ()
  "Switch to the most recently visited window, as stored in
`recent-window'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((current (car (window-list))))
    (if recent-window
        (select-window recent-window)
      (message (concat "No recent window selected, "
                       "so I'm setting this window "
                       "as the most recent.")))
    (setq recent-window current)))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Do you mind if I make a package out of it, with attribution?

Comment: You're welcome.  Sure, feel free to use it in a package, but be aware that the code in not (yet) very intelligent.  If you switch to other windows with commands such as `next-window` or `other-window`, the change won't get picked up in the `recent-window` variable.  There's no obvious hook to use, so fixing this part may involve defining advice for a whole bunch of other functions.

Comment: I think you could use `buffer-list-update-hook`, which is called when the active window changes (after `select-window`). That hook is called in other cases but could be used to keep track of the last window.